# Get Data from another website using google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to do some data analytics. I am trying to get the data from a website(whose permission I have) using google analytics. All the tutorials I found were of getting the data from your own website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issues you need to add tracking code google analytics to website, if you don't have permission to add this tracking code, there is no solution

Comment: The website in question has google analytics enabled and I have their permission to get the data.My question is how to get the data

Comment: @ubuntu_noob ohh sorry bro, you can see your data from your analytics dashboard, or you can use api from google analytics https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting

Comment: I couldnt understand how to set up my account and get the data from another persons website